# JS closure application issue

Tags: javascript, closures

```
function multFn(num){
    return function(factor){
        return factor*num
    }
}

var multFive=multFn(5)
console.log(multFive(2))    // outputs 10
```

The question?:

How does JS know that when I console.log(multFive(2)) that the 2 should be given to the factor parameter? I know that multFn will return a pointer to the method inside it. But I don't get how the 2 gets assigned to factor.

Comment: `2` gets assigned to `factor` the exact same way `5` gets assigned to `num`, it is an argument to a function call. `console.log(multFive.toString());` might help you see that `multFive` is just a normal function that takes one argument.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the first function causes the inner one to be returned to your variable. When you invoke that function, the argument you pass goes to the parameter the second function is expecting.

When you run this first line:

```
var multFive = multFn(5);
```

The outer function (`multFn`) is invoked and `5` is received as `num`, so the function operates like this:

```
function multFn(5){
    return function(factor){
        return factor * 5
    }
}
```

But, that function has a `return` in it that returns the inner function to your `multFive` variable, so you wind up with this:

```
var multFive = function(factor){
  return factor * 5;
}
```

Finally, when you invoke `multFive` and pass it a `2`, the `2` becomes the value of the `factor` argument that the function is expecting.

```
console.log(multFive(2));
```

Causes:

```
function(2){
  return 2 * 5;
}
```

And, `2 * 5` = `10`.

NOTE: I've shown what the functions will execute based on the code you've supplied. There is an advanced concept in JavaScript, called ["Closures"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) that could make it so that the outer function doesn't always have to statically run with `5` as its value. But, for the purposes of your question, that's not relevant.

Comment: That makes it look like `num` is substituted with its value at the time the inner function is returned. While that makes no difference in this example it would be an important difference if `num` was every modified after `multFn(5)` was called.

Answer (score 0):

This is really an example of [function currying](https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/).  Essentially you are returning a function from a function, with some of the needed values already specified during the creation of the returned function.

Calling `multFn(5)` creates a closure around an anonymous function, and that closure has a reference to `num` as being 5.

The function that is returned is equivalent to:

```
function(factor){
  var num=5;
  return num * factor;
}
```

and is assigned to the reference `multFive`.

Inside your `console.log(multFive(2))` you are calling that returned function `multFive` with the argument 2, and you get your result of 2*5=10.

Comment: Awesome!  Wanted to be sure you knew about the concept of currying.  It's a little tricky at first, but can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion because you think that the result of the assignment:

```
var multFive = multFn(5);
```

Will be something like this:

```
var multFive = function multFn(num) { //num is passed 5
    return function(factor) {
        return factor * num;
    };
}
```

But that's not the case. It will actually be something like this:

```
var multFive = function(factor) {
    return factor * num;
}
```

And the value 5 is assigned to the `num` variable in the closure. On the next line:

```
console.log(multFive(2));
```

You're passing 2 directly to the `factor` parameter and it will be multiplied by the value of `num` that was stored in the closure earlier.

To see that in action (a proof of that), print out the `multFive`:

```
console.log(multFive);
```

Here is a funny quiz, try to guess the output and then run it to see:

```js
function multFn(num) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    num = 3;
  }, 500);
  return function(factor) {
    return factor * num;
  };
}

var multFive = multFn(5);
console.log(multFive(2)); // outputs 10

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(multFive(2)); //what will the output be here?
}, 1000);
```